# Is there a way to list all the current GCP ressources or project ids from an organization with a sql bigquery query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I am looking for a way to list all the current project ids with an SQL query so that I can later execute it with dbt.

I have tried with extracting the project id from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION, but it also contains deleted projects, which I dont have a way to distinguish and since I later acess them in the code it breaks

Comment: Is it a must to use a GoogleSQL query? `gcloud` command line tool would be a better fit for this task: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list

Comment: It could work if I can execute a cloud shell command from dbt and get the results. Do you know if there is a way? Can't seems to find anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not out of the box. You have to use [Cloud Asset Inventory to export your asset to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery) and then query them

I share with you the command for organization level (not documented)

```
gcloud asset export --organization=<Your Org ID> \
 --content-type=resource \
 --bigquery-table=projects/<your projectID>/datasets/<Your Dataset>/tables/<Your table> \
 --output-bigquery-force
```

Then, get the `cloudresourcemanager.Project` resource type to get all your project ID in your organization.